# Calculating deviation from line y=x of bivariate data

Tags: python, pandas, statistics

As shown below, I have bivariate data, and in an ideal world, this data would fit the straight line (y=x).  In Python, how do I calculate the deviation of each point from that line (y=x)?  Is it possible to quantify the mean deviation from that straight line fit?  I'm just trying to think of a way to quantify how my data varies from a 1:1 ratio.  Any suggestions are appreciated.   I am working with data set up in a Pandas DataFrame. Thanks.

[image]

Comment: do you mean `y_hat - y`? Usually you see [MSE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_squared_error) used, or maybe if you want MAE... either one.

Comment: OP, (predicted value) minus (actual value) is typically called the residual error in discussions of regression problems. Try searching for "residuals" or "residual error" in Pandas or maybe Numpy or Scipy.

Answer (score 1):

This code will calculate the deviation of each point from the regression line and also from the line y=x and also will plot the standard deviation as well as the regression and y=x function.

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
import statistics as stat


#Set the x and y values
x=np.random.rand(50)
y=2*x-1+np.random.rand(50)



"""
calculate the deviation from y=x at each point
"""

xp=np.linspace(0,1,50)
yp=xp
deviationxy=(y-yp)

listpos=[]
listneg=[]

#Calculate the ratio of the points
[listpos.append(i) for i in deviationxy if i >0]
[listneg.append(i) for i in deviationxy if i <0]

if len(listpos)==len(listneg):
    print("The ratio is 1:1")
else:
    above=(len(listpos)/len(deviationxy))*100
    below=(len(listneg)/len(deviationxy))*100
    print("{0}% of the values are above the line y=x ; {1}% of the values are below the line".format(above,below))


"""
Implement the regression
"""

#coerce the x values in the shape [n_samples,n_features]
X=x[:,np.newaxis]


#inistantiate the model
model=LinearRegression(fit_intercept=True)

#fit the model
model.fit(X,y)


#print the dots and the regression function as well as the fumction x=y
fig,ax=plt.subplots(figsize=(10,10))
ax.scatter(x,y)
ax.plot(x,model.coef_*x+model.intercept_,":r")
ax.plot(xp,yp,".k")


#calculate the devaition from regression at each point
deviation=np.sqrt((y-(model.coef_*x+model.intercept_))**2)
print(deviation)#returns the deviation for each point



#plot the standard_deviation from the regression line

standard_deviation=stat.stdev(x)

std_dev=[standard_deviation,-standard_deviation]
[ax.plot(x,(model.coef_*x+model.intercept_)+standard,"--b") for standard in std_dev]

plt.show()
```

[image]